# Run Python module in another code but with an older version

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.10 but I want to run a Python module with Python 3.6 and use the result inside my code(that written with Python 3.10)

Please help me to solve it
thanks

Comment: Solve what? What is the problem? What happens when you try to do it?

Comment: idk how to do it, that is my proble

Comment: I don't think it is possible to run your program in two different versions of Python together. It is also a very odd requirement. Can't you make your code all work in 3.10?

Comment: Is your question how you can run any code with Python 3.6 instead of Python 3.10? Do you have Python 3.6 installed?

Comment: Why don't you run the other module also with Python 3.10?

Comment: @mkrieger1 i have to use scikit-learn 0.20.2 module but it is not available for Python 3.10

Comment: Do you already have both 3.10 and 3.6 installed, or do you need to get that set up first?

Comment: @CrazyChucky no i set up everything

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a `.py` script that should be run with python3.6
2. Make the script prints your expected result

```
# script.py
import sys

print(sys.version[:6])
```

3. Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to get it

```
import subprocess

python3_6_result = subprocess.check_output(["python3.6", "script.py"])
print(python3_6_result) # 3.6.15
```